# List MongoDB databases names using regex

Tags: mongodb

In example when I use following query

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach( function (d) {
     print ( d.name )
})
```

I get following result

```
admin
config
config2
customer1_tnt1
customer2_tnt1
```

I want to list only those DBs that in result contain string "tnt", because there may be multiple customers and multiple tnt users. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Umm `db.adminCommand({ "listDatabases": 1, "filter": { "name": { "$regex": "tnt" } }})`. There is note of `filter` [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/)

Comment: FYI, *slightly* changing your question title as a google search [MongoDB listdatabases names using regex](https://www.google.com/search?q=+MongoDB+listdatabases+names+using+regex) (basically using `listdatbases` as a command name instead of separate words ) returns the manual page and the linked duplicate within the top few results.

Comment: Yes it does help me together with your first answer. Correctly marked as duplicate